# How can I play multiple gifs in sync? (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gif

I am building an app that displays a customizable avatar using overlayed divs with CSS background sprites that are gifs. Currently, I am setting the background image using inline component styling, like this:

`` <div id="head" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${headSheet})`}}/> ``

`` <div id="hat" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${hatSheet})`}}/> ``

This works most of the time, but occasionally when loading the page the gifs will not start at the same time and so the animations will not be in sync. I have tried these solutions:

- [Load and display multiple animated gifs at the same time (synchronised) with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878030/load-and-display-multiple-animated-gifs-at-the-same-time-synchronised-with-jav)
- [How synchronize more gif pictures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515410/how-synchronize-more-gif-pictures)

but they did not work for me. They are also fairly old, so hopefully there is a more modern solution using React.

Answer (score 0):

Really, you won't be able to do what you want consistently with an animated gif, or set of gifs.

You should probably break each frame into a separate gif/png (you can do transparent png at <= 256 color palette with alpha transparency, so may be a better option).  [Combine this with a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164181/how-to-fetch-a-remote-image-to-display-in-a-canvas), and control the swapping via JS.  Look into [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) as well for your control flow.

You should combine this with the useEffect hook to register/unregister your animation shifts.  You will likely want to manipulate the canvas element directly (useRef) as opposed to having React handle (re)renders.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which waits for all images on the page to load, then loops through each image and resets its `src` which causes the browser to restart the animation.

```js
Promise.all(Array.from(document.images).filter(img => !img.complete).map(img => new Promise(resolve => { img.onload = img.onerror = resolve; }))).then(() => {
    console.log('images finished loading');
    images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (image of images) {
        image.src = image.getAttribute("src");
    }
});
```

Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60949881/7465444   https://stackoverflow.com/a/64017942/7465444